# How do I set up a React project on Synology NAS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, create-react-app, synology

I'm trying to set up a create-react-app project on my 918+ Synology NAS. From the getgo it has Node.js 5.6.0, but since create-react-app requires >=6 I need to install and use a higher version. Within the Synology NAS the Package Manger has both Node.js 6 and 8. These install fine. Then I'm trying to change the current Node.js version, this is where the problems starts.

For the information, the Synology runs a custom distro of Linux called DSM, with kernel 4.4.59.

When trying to change to version using e.g. `nvm use 6.12.3` I get:

```
Error: Could not open history file.
REPL session history will not be persisted.
```

Googling this gives me no results. Is there somewhere here that would happen to know what to do, or just could try help me get this set up? I'm not sure if it's even possible. The Synology has Docker, would that be a better option for me?

Comment: Are you sure the error is actually fatal? It sounds harmless. If you consider it a problem, check if you're unable to create/write to `~/.node_repl_history`, or whether you have `NODE_REPL_HISTORY` set to something weird